# Angular NGX Swimlane chart component as dynamic component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to pass one of the NGX Swimlane Chart components into my dialog instance, but I keep getting this error:

```
ASSERTION ERROR: Type passed in is not ComponentType, it does not have 'ɵcmp' property.
```

**Parent component that displays the charts nicely:**

```
<ngx-charts-pie-chart
    [results]="chartStats"
    [doughnut]="false" #pieChartComponent>
</ngx-charts-pie-chart>
```

**Injection code:**

```
....
@ViewChild('pieChartComponent') public pieChartComp: PieChartComponent;
...
public openChartDialog(): void {
   this.dialog.open(ChartDialogComponent, {
       width: environment.dialogWidth,
       data: this.pieChartComp,
   });
}
```

**Dialog component itself where the error is**

```
export class ChartDialogComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    @ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) public vcRef: ViewContainerRef;

    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
    public componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

    constructor(
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
        private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    ) {
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.data);
        this.componentRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory);
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (this.componentRef) {
            this.componentRef.destroy();
        }
    }

}
```

**dialog html**

```
<div mat-dialog-title
     cdkDrag
     cdkDragRootElement=".cdk-overlay-pane"
     cdkDragHandle>
    {{'STATS.CHART_DETAILS' | translate}}
</div>
<mat-dialog-content>
    <ng-template #target></ng-template>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button mat-raised-button
            mat-dialog-close>
        <mat-icon>
            cancel_presentation
        </mat-icon>
        {{'COMMON.CLOSE' | translate}}
    </button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

I've also tried using cdk portal for dynamic component injection, but it didn't work and also showed the same error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: just repalce ngOnInit() with ngAfterViewInit() in dialgo component where your are creating reference of component inside `ChartDialogComponent` I think then its all working fine.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda same error.

Comment: Can you show, working demo of this issue ? @DenissM.

Comment: Your approach to pass component reference to dialog is not right. You have to pass template ref to dialog, and this is the way you can create your dialog. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gy4sbz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-overview-example.html here is link you can get working example.  @DenissM.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I have a separate component for the dialog and then there is another component (dynamic) which is injected into that specific one.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't pass the component correctly.

I was doing this when opening the dialog:

```
data: this.pieChartComp,
```

But I had to do this:

```
data: PieChartComponent,
```

This at least resolves the issue with the initial error, but the data that was bound to the component is not passed. But that is another issue I guess.

Answer (score -1):

I could help you with different provider [ngx-awesome-popup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@costlydeveloper/ngx-awesome-popup), check this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/minimal-dialog-setup?file=src/app/app.component.ts) and [this](https://costlydeveloper.github.io/ngx-awesome-popup/#/basic-example/dialog) that doesn't need to be complicated.

In parent component:

```
public openChartDialog(): void {
        const dialogPopup = new DialogInitializer(ChartDialogComponent);
        dialogPopup.setCustomData(this.pieChartComp);
        dialogPopup.setConfig({
              Width     : environment.dialogWidth, // ex. '500px',
              LayoutType: DialogLayoutDisplay.NONE // SUCCESS | INFO | NONE | DANGER | WARNING
        });
        dialogPopup.setButtons([
            new ButtonMaker('OK', 'ok', ButtonLayoutDisplay.SUCCESS),
            new ButtonMaker('Cancel', 'cancel', ButtonLayoutDisplay.SECONDARY)
        ]);
    
       const subscription = dialogPopup.openDialog$().subscribe(resp => {
            console.log('dialog response: ', resp);
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        });
    }
```

And in dynamic component:

```
export class ChartDialogComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    
    private subscriptions: Subscription = new Subscription();
    
    // Dependency Injection of the dialogBelonging in constructor is crucial.
    constructor(private dialogBelonging: DialogBelonging) {}
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Check received data and other available features.
        console.log(this.dialogBelonging);
        
        // Subscribe to button listeners.
        this.subscriptions.add(
            // IDialogEventsController
            this.dialogBelonging.EventsController.onButtonClick$.subscribe((_Button) => {
                if (_Button.ID === 'ok') {
                    
                    // Do some logic and close popup.
                    this.dialogBelonging.EventsController.close();
                }
                else if (_Button.ID === 'cancel') {
                    
                    // Do some logic and close popup.
                    this.dialogBelonging.EventsController.close();
                }
            })
        );
        
        // Timeout emulates async data.
        setTimeout(() => {
            // Close the loader after data is ready.
            // IDialogEventsController
            this.dialogBelonging.EventsController.closeLoader();
        }, 1000);
    }
    
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // Care about memory and close all subscriptions.
        this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```